# In php how do we call (int) (array) (object) ? Where to find more info about those?

Tags: php

I was aware of (int) and (array) but not (object) and probably others.

I'm wondering **a) what is the proper name of those "things";** and, **b) where can we found more information about those?** (I was unable to find (object) on php.net website.

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: What result do you expect from (object)?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean. But I do expect that, once we apply (object) the value gets transformed into an object...

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I don't know what MEM expects ;-) but the documentation says: http://docs.php.net/language.types.object#language.types.object.casting

Comment: The reason why I'm using this, is for testing proposes. I will receive some stdClass on the main application but, for testing proposes, I needed to pass this easy and fast to make array, into a stdClass object, just to see if json_encode will work on that to. That, btw, it works. :D Only this. :D

Comment: be careful of (string) on an object. it may not consistently return the expected value due to the different kinds of objects and whether they implement __toString() or __set_state() methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [type casting/conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).
see http://docs.php.net/language.types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks for that add on. I was actually not aware of primitives and objects and their differences. ;)

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Be very careful!

If you try something like

```
$array = array(5, 2, 3);
$object = (object)$array;
print_r($object);
echo $object->2;
```

you'll end up with

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in - on line 5
```

Really, the safest way to convert from arrays to objects is pretty convoluted but works alright:

```
public function makeObjects($data)
{
    $object = (object) $data;
    foreach ($object as $property)
    {
        if (is_array($property)) $this->makeObjects($property);
    }

    return $object;
}
```

Comment: Ummm...  `$object = (object) $array` works quite fine...  The reason for your fatal error is because `$object->2` is not a valid syntax.  It's not related to the conversion...

Comment: as far as I can see the code inside the foreach does nothing meaningful

Comment: Used:
$response = (object) array(
    'success' => TRUE,
    'data'    => array(1, 2, 3)
);

No issues there. ;)

Comment: @Tom Haigh: Um, it converts nested arrays into nested objects.  How is that not useful?

Comment: the bit inside the foreach doesn't do anything with the return value of makeObjects()